# SQLite two tables matching logic

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I have two tables in my SQLite database one is a table of everything (`main`), another is a "favorites" table (`favorites`) and I want to load a `Cursor` for my `ListView` and have a star greyed out or yellow if its in `favorites`. Both tables have the exact same columns and I was hoping to load a `Cursor` with these columns and an additional column `favorite` that can be a boolean or a 1 or 0. The favorite row is simply copied from the `main` table, so its contents will be the same. Then, when the star is tapped, update the `favorites` table and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my adapter and that should update the `ListView`.

I've tried using `JOIN` and loading tables with `AS` aliases but I'm having trouble. Can anyone help me with a SQLite query to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` I've been able to achieve what I want and added a column `is_fav` in the `favorites` table.

```
SELECT M.*, F.is_fav
FROM main AS M
LEFT JOIN favorites AS F ON M.title = F.title
```

This may seem odd to add that column but its used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select like this

```
SELECT M.FieldA, M.FieldB,... M.Fieldx,  
FROM MainTable AS M JOIN Favorites as F 
ON M.Id = F.Id;
```

In this example Id is the matching field. Additionally you can replace M.FiledX by isnull(M.Fieldx, 'something') or any other function. But, essentially if M.Fieldx returns null, then it is not in the favorites.

Also it's worth to say that in your favorites table you don't need to duplicate the row, just save the ID of the record in your main table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, but it was not working for me. It was returning only the items in common where I wanted to have the items in common have a new column with a true and false for the not in common. However, you did point me in the right direction with ISNULL. I've used this with UNION ALL and two SELECT calls to get what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Oh and I was duplicating the entire row because that table is also used in other cases.

Comment: @chis54 Actually I now realize that you're totally right about the query returning only rows in common. To have all items returned (not only the ones in common) you have to do an `outer join` (it can be a right join or a left join).

Comment: Thank you. I did end up using a LEFT JOIN rather than the UNION ALL, which was causing other issues. Thank you for your suggestion, though, it was what lead me to get my situation figure out :-)